# Cast issue with CaptureFileAsync()

Tags: vb.net, casting, webcam

I'm trying to figure out how to call windows camera UI from a windows form.

I did this and it does compile:

```
Public Function ShootPicture() As StorageFile
    Dim captureUI As New CameraCaptureUI
    captureUI.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg
    captureUI.PhotoSettings.AllowCropping = False
    Dim GetPhotoTask As Task(Of StorageFile) = captureUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo)
    GetPhotoTask.Wait() ' Blocks current thread until CaptureFileAsync task completes'
    Dim result As StorageFile = GetPhotoTask.Result
    Return result
End Function
```

But there is a 'System.InvalidCastException' execution error on .capturefileAsync() : type 'System._ComObject' cannot be casted as 'System.threading.tasks.task'

Would anyone have any idea on how to fix this? Thanks

If it can help here is the c# code translation:

```
public StorageFile ShootPicture()
{
    CameraCaptureUI captureUI = new CameraCaptureUI();
    captureUI.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
    captureUI.PhotoSettings.AllowCropping = false;
    Task<StorageFile> GetPhotoTask = captureUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
    GetPhotoTask.Wait();
    // Blocks current thread until CaptureFileAsync task completes
    StorageFile result = GetPhotoTask.Result;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CaptureFileAsync returns an [IAsyncOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.iasyncoperation_tresult_), so try using await instead of a Task:

```
Dim result As StorageFile = Await captureUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping N0Alias.
The issue is that await needs the function to be declared Async , and I can't, because it's destined to be called from a Protected Overrides Function. (If I make it Async the signature changes, and the override fail)
My attempt was to make if synchronous instead of async.

Comment: Anyway, I even tried your solution on an async function, it does not compile:
`Error 2: The expression type is'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation(Of Windows.Storage.StorageFile)', and thus cannot be awaited`

Comment: Yeah if the method you were overriding could be decorated with the Async decorator that error would go away.  Maybe make a new Async method with this code in it that gets called from the one you are overriding.

Comment: Hi @N0Alias, I tried your solution on an button_click async sub, and it still does not compile.. It says "The expression type is IAsyncOperation and cannot be awaited" Any idea?

Comment: That's because you're stuck overriding that method.  If you could mark that method with Async it would work.

Comment: Hello, I manage to compile and run this code:
  'Dim GetPhotoTask As Task(Of StorageFile) = capture.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo).AsTask
        Dim Photo As StorageFile = Await GetPhotoTask
        MsgBox(Photo.Path)'

(It had to be casted as task with the windows runtime extension)

However, I still have an issue: the camera app never shows, and the code always returns Photo=nothing
Any idea? @N0Alias ?